# Generating Fibonacci sequences in Scala

Tags: scala, fibonacci-sequence

Would you consider this to be idiomatic Scala? If not, what would you do to improve it?

```
def fibonaccis(max: Int): List[Int] = { fibonaccis(max, 2, 1) }
private def fibonaccis(max: Int, prev: Int, prevPrev: Int): List[Int] = prev >= max match {
  case true => List[Int](prevPrev)
  case false => prevPrev :: fibonaccis(max, prev + prevPrev, prev)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naming the parameters `prev` and `prevPrev` is weird.  Why not `current` and `prev`?

You shouldn't need the curly braces here for a function that consists of a single expression:

```
def fibonaccis(max: Int): List[Int] = fibonaccis(max, 2, 1)
```

[Conventionally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), the Fibonacci sequence is said to start like

$$1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, \ldots$$

or

$$0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, \ldots$$

Your `fibonaccis(13)` would produce `List(1, 2, 3, 5, 8)`, which I would consider to be missing the first element.

---

The Fibonacci sequence is an infinite sequence.  It would be a shame to limit it to a `max` value.  The most idiomatic way to model it in Scala would be using an infinite lazy stream, just as [suggested in the documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_14.html):

```
def fibFrom(a: Int, b: Int): Stream[Int] = a #:: fibFrom(b, a + b)
val fibonaccis = fibFrom(0, 1)
```

[Alternative implementation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream):

```
val fibonaccis: Stream[Int] = 0 #:: 1 #:: fibonaccis.zip(fibonaccis.tail).map(
    n => n._1 + n._2
)
```

Then, you could do `fibonaccis.takeWhile(_ < 13).toList` to obtain `List(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8)`.

Comment: I'm not crazy about prev and prevPrev. Not current, though, since it's not the current value, it's the previous. Awkward either way. I like the stream approach - thought the answer might include that, but I haven't gotten that far yet. When is the next value generated? Is it just in time?

Comment: Streams are lazy. Each successive element is computed as needed, and memoized for the future.